# How disable Copy, Select All in UITextView using swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

How disable Copy, Select All in `UITextView`, But i need link is clickable in `UITextview`.

Here is all action disable, But selection is allow. I need only clickable link.

```
override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {

        return false
}
```

Comment: Is the textView editable or not?

Comment: no editable @Ahmet

Comment: editable but not selectable?

Comment: ya i need only allow clickable links.

Comment: You can disable selection with textView.isSelectable = false. if you make it not isSelectable, links also does not work. Apple says that "This property controls the ability of the user to select content and interact with URLs and text attachments. The default value is YES."

Comment: @Digvijay did you manage to solve this? I am in similar situation, I want to disable all actions, but enable links / emails etc...

Answer (score 0):

just `hijack` it,

```
func swizzle() {
    guard let cls = NSClassFromString("UITextSelectionView") else { return }
    let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString("updateSelectionRects")
    let swizzledSelector = #selector(UIView.updateSelectionRectsHijack)
    let originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    let swizzleMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIView.self, swizzledSelector)
    if let swizzledMethod = swizzleMethod, let originalMethod = originMethod{
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
}

extension UIView{
    @objc func updateSelectionRectsHijack(){ }
}
```

`swizzle()` should be call once only.

---

How I know `UITextSelectionView` ?

Check `View Hierarchy`,

[image: 888]

---

How I know method `updateSelectionRects` ?

via `runtime`,

`import ObjectiveC` ,

then,

```
        var count: UInt32 = 0
        guard let methodArr = class_copyMethodList(NSClassFromString("UITextSelectionView"), &count) else { return }
        
        let cnt = Int(count)
        for i in 0..<cnt{
            let method = methodArr[i]
            let name = method_getName(method)
            if let type = method_getTypeEncoding(method){
                print(name, String(utf8String: type) ?? " _ | _ ")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also hijack, like this

```
let hijackInvocation: @convention(block) (Unmanaged<NSObject>, AnyObject) -> Void = { objectRef, invocation in
    
}


func swizzle() {

    guard let cls = NSClassFromString("UITextLoupeInteraction") else { return }
    let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString("loupeGesture:")
    let originMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(cls, originalSelector)
    if let originM = originMethod{
        let encode = method_getTypeEncoding(originM)
        class_replaceMethod(cls, originalSelector, imp_implementationWithBlock(hijackInvocation as Any), encode)
    }
}
```

`swizzle()` should be call just once.

---

what is `UITextLoupeInteraction` ?

[image: 999]

from @dengST30's answer.